# Is Secp256k1's prime prime?

Tags: prime-numbers, cryptography, primality-test

Bitcoin protocol relies on the elliptic curve [secp256k1](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Secp256k1) for its cryptographic security.
For that purpose the integer number $p = 2^{256}-2^{32}-977$ must be prime.
How do they know $p$ is actually prime? I mean, **which primality test can be used to prove it?**

Comment: A number of that size (about 80 digits) can be comfortably _factored_ within a few minutes these days, AFAIK; primality testing complete with a certificate can probably be found within a few seconds. See e.g. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Atkin-Goldwasser-Kilian-MorainCertificate.html

Comment: Modern practice is to use Curve25519 or Curve448 as the underlying elliptic curve; they are "rigid".

Comment: @Parcly Why is that important in primality testing and verification?

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out in the comments, this is not a large number to factorise with modern methods.

The Magma online calculator http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/ verifies that it is prime, when asked to factor it, almost instantly.

> time Factorisation(2^256-2^32-977);

returns

> [ <115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663, 1> ]
> Time: 0.070

as the factorisation into powers of primes; the number $2^{256}-2^{32}-977$ is a single prime to the power $1$. It takes 0.07 seconds to get this result.

Primality testing is consistent as well.

> time IsPrime(2^256-2^32-977);

yields

> true
> Time: 0.060

Comment: $0.0008$ sec with *Mathematica* on a laptop Intel i7

Comment: @Raffaele Does *Mathematica* show this rigorously by default, or just indicate that it is a probably prime? Magma will do this in "0.000" seconds with the parameter `Proof:=false` (at least on my i7 laptop), which will confirm $p$ to be a strong pseudoprime to 20 bases.

Comment: @MorganRodgers There are two ways to know primality PrimeQ[n] or FactorInteger[n] and both are deterministic. With the second I got the result in $0.00072$ seconds

Comment: @Raffaele I looked at this out of curiosity, it turns out that Mathematica does not in fact verify (rigorously) the results of `PrimeQ[n]` (or by extension that the integers returned by `FactorInteger[n]` are prime); to do that you need to use `ProvablePrimeQ[n]`. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PrimalityProving/tutorial/PrimalityProving

Comment: FWIW, the online Magma calculator prints an ECPP primality certificate for this number in 0.08 seconds (using the `PrimalityCertificate` function).

Comment: @MorganRodgers very interesting! Now it took about $0.9$ seconds. I always wondered how could it be so fast and now I know. Thank you

Comment: I never doubted the existence of software packages doing the job. Could you elaborate on "factorise with modern methods"?

Comment: @Lagrange.el.Ciencia Magma uses (in the more rigorous version) the ECCP algorithm detailed here https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1993-61-203/S0025-5718-1993-1199989-X/S0025-5718-1993-1199989-X.pdf while the less rigorous version uses the probablistic Miller-Rabin test. These methods are probably too technical to fit into a MSE answer though.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Mention the name of the methods and give references without getting into technical details would be a good answer.

Comment: @Morgan We have numerous questions on this site related to Miller-Rabin primality testing, both deterministic and non-deterministic versions. (I even posted some Python code that does deterministic M-R [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1638487/207316)). OTOH, Elliptic Curve Primality Proving is rather more complex. Just explaining the necessary prerequisites: the properties of elliptic curves, projective geometry, and finite field arithmetic, would probably exceed the answer byte limit. ;)

Comment: We do have a handful of questions here that come up in a search: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=elliptic+curve+primality but I don't know how technical or detailed they are (yet).

Comment: @Lagrange.el.Ciencia I see from your profile that you have some familiarity with group theory, so you should be able to follow the core concepts of ECPP, so take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_primality  It may help to first read the article about Lenstra's elliptic curve factorisation (see the link at the bottom of that page).