# What is the significance (if any) of being able to deterministically calculate the gap to the next prime number in this way?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

*(Hello, this is my first post here so I hope I do a good job of laying it out. I am happy to clarify or clean up examples if it might help out.)*

Consider a table of numbers (n - horizontal axis) and all potential factors (f - vertical), with modular remainders n % f laid out on a grid as follows:

[image: table of n % f]

It's easy to visualise how each factor contributes to the emergence of prime numbers (marked P) - just find the vertical columns where the count of 0s = 2.

I was trying to understand how modular remainders relate to prime distances, as I've been trying to better understand the cause and limits of prime gaps.

Clearly the remainders in the above form only ever show the distance from previous iterations of each factor, so are useless for looking ahead.

That made me wonder what would happen if I negated n, such that the below table shows factors of -n % f:

[image: table of -n % f]

In doing so, remainders now effectively represent the distances to "future" cycles of a given factor, where the "future" is toward the left of the table.

A pattern caught my eye in regards to prime gaps. For example if you look at the selected cells above, the lowest missing modular remainder when n=-7 is 4, which is the distance to the next prime number (albeit negative), -11.

Intuitively this makes sense; there won't be an explicit distance to the next prime number in any of the remainders of -n % f, because the next prime doesn't "exist" yet. But for any given n, the first missing remainder of -n % f is exactly the count to the next prime.

I wrote some quick and dirty code and tested successfully for tens of thousands of consecutive primes and a few relatively large ones (relative to a home PC running any kind of O(n^2) algorithm I guess). A cut down example is below:

https://jsfiddle.net/alexofparker/v0hg1r6x/13/

(I do have an optimised version that only requires mods of -n % 2, -n % 3 etc, which does the same thing many times faster, but is less obvious)

**Is this way of calculating the prime gap significant in any way?**

Conventional wisdom from what I've read and understood so far *seems* to be that there's no general & deterministic way to find the distance to the next prime number that doesn't involve counting up one number at a time from some start point and running a prime factorisation on each candidate.

I understand that various sieves both ancient and modern can vastly speed that process up as we can skip over a majority of repeating factor's cycles (e.g. for a period of 60).

But as I understand, sieves are non-deterministic; a sieve won't be able to tell you that the next prime number is exactly x digits from n.

Whereas although fairly clunky, it appears that finding the missing modular remainder of all potential factors of negative n can tell us the exact distance from any n to the next prime number.

So I guess, is what specific area in mathematics can teach me more about this pattern I've stumbled on - is there anything deeper here I can learn from and extend my knowledge? Am I just overthinking something elementary, or what am I missing?

Appreciate any and all insights into these questions!

Comment: I don't think your algorithm for distance to previous prime is correct. For $n=5$ the distance to the previous prime is $2$ but the first $\frac{5}{2}+1=3$ entries under the $5$ column contain the number $2$.

Comment: If you have a very large number, then finding the next or the previous prime is only possible by sieving out small factors and checking the remaining candidates (they need not to be factorized, this would soon lead to practical limits). A good survey over the prime gaps is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap). Note that the best known upper bounds for the prime gaps are probably extremely weak.

Comment: @StevenClark good point. I'll remove mention to previous primes now, it was something I noticed after I found the pointer to the next prime and didn't test as thoroughly. Apologies if it wasted any time. I think it works for larger values of n but I haven't tested it as I say. I think I'd prefer this question to focus on the next prime gap so I'll remove mention to previous primes for now. Thanks!

Comment: @Peter thanks, I understand all of that for the most part, however the bit about "they need not be factorized" intrigues me, how can you check if a bunch of prime candidates are prime without factorizing? Appreciate the response, thanks for looking at my questions :)

Comment: I believe your algorithm for distance to previous prime may work if you change $f\le\frac{n}{2}+1$ to $f\le\frac{n}{2}$ which I tested for $n$ up to $10000$.

Comment: Thanks @StevenClark that's what my initial code did https://github.com/AlexanderParker/nextprime.js/blob/main/nextprime.js#L42 but I second guessed I suppose. Thanks for verifying!

Comment: The Adleman Pomerance Rumely test can check numbers with several thousand digits for primality in some hours (with proof that the number is prime). It would take an eternity to factor them in general. A quick test (for an odd number) is whether $$2^{n-1}\equiv 1\mod n$$ holds which can be efficiently checked. If this does not hold, the number cannot be prime. Of course, even numbers need not be tested, since $2$ is the only even prime number.

Comment: If you are content with a so-called "probable prime" (which means with probability $0.999999$ or more) , you can even check numbers with a hundred thousand digits in a reasonable time. The result "composite" is always correct. Miller Rabin is such a test or the extremely reliable BPSW-test with no known counterexample. In short : It is significantly easier to check whether a number is prime than to find a nontrivial factor.

Comment: Your algorithm to find the next prime / prime gap is related to the [segmented sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Segmented_sieve).

Comment: FWIW, [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1638487/207316) shows how to use a deterministic version of the Miller-Rabin test to attack a problem related to prime gaps.